# how to replace the characters in strings with '#'s by using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

How can I replace the contents of strings with `#`'s in Python? Assume no comments, no multiple lines for one string. Like if there is a line in a python file:

```
print 'Hello' + "her mom's shirt".
```

This will be translated into:

```
print '#####' + "###############".
```

It's like a filter to deal with every line in a python file.

Comment: "The strings" in what exactly?

Comment: I mean the string in the python file.
Like 'I'm superman', then it will be replace as '############',
More straightly, just replace the content in the ' ' or " " by #s.

Comment: Please read, for the benefit of everyone: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: This can't be done (reliably) using regex only. You'll have to parse the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s="The Strings"
>>> s=re.sub("\w","#",s)
>>> s
'### #######'
>>> s='Hello' + "her mom's shirt"
>>> s
"Helloher mom's shirt"
>>> re.sub("\w","#",s)
"######## ###'# #####"
```

----Edit

OK, Now I understand that you want the output to be from a Python file. Try:

```
import fileinput
import re 

for line in fileinput.input():
    iter = re.finditer(r'(\'[^\']+\'|"[^"]+")',line)
    for m in iter:
       span = m.span()
       paren = m.group()[0]
       line = line[:span[0]]+paren+'#'*(span[1]-span[0]-2)+paren+line[span[1]:] 
       print line.rstrip()
```

This does not deal with line breaks, the """ form, and is only tested again 1 or two files I have...

In general, it is better to use a parser for this kind of job.

Best

Comment: What I expect is just the characters in string will be replaced, but not the result after combination of the two strings.

Comment: @antonio081014: Based on the responses you are getting, it should be very clear to you that your question is not clear. You said in your post "It's like a filter to deal with every line in a python file." Are you saying you want to process a group of Python source files in another script?

Comment: @drewk: What I want is write this python script to deal with python file.

Comment: I think the question is quite clear now that he added the examples.

Comment: @drewk: Thank you very much. I finally got it. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Python and the thing you're parsing is Python there's no need to use regexp since [there's a built-in parser](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/ast.html).

Answer (score 1):

Don't need a regex to replace `"I'm superman"` with `"############"`

Try

```
input = "I'm superman"
print "#" * len(input)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the case is I need to practice my python skill

Comment: Well if you wanted to do above with a regex it would be something like `print re.sub('.', '#', input)

Comment: you're missing the point. The source is supposed to be a python file from which the strings are to be parsed.

Comment: @AaronMcSmooth, yes the question changed while I was writing my answer. You got to be quick round here. I was responding to antonio's comment on his own question at the time.